# Button is not aligned properly - WPF

Tags: wpf, xaml, button, border

I have a button inside a Stackpanel that seems to have a padding but I have already set it to 0

this shows the button's backgroung that is shifted from the button border

[image: 1]

Is there any special margin, border or other setting that I might be missing?

Here is the XAML:

```
<StackPanel Orientation="Vertical"
        VerticalAlignment="Center"
        HorizontalAlignment="Center">
    <Button x:Name="btnOpcion1"
        Style="{StaticResource BtnPrincipal}"/>
</StackPanel>
```

This is the style:

```
<Style x:Key="BtnPrincipal" TargetType="Button">
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource AzulAquaOscuro}" />
        <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0" />
        <Setter Property="Height" Value="40" />
        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="White" />
        <Setter Property="Width" Value="200" />
        <Setter Property="Padding" Value="0" />
        <Setter Property="Margin" Value="5" />
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
                    <Border Background="{TemplateBinding Background}">
                        <ContentPresenter HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                                          VerticalAlignment="Center" />
                    </Border>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
        <Style.Triggers>
            <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource AzulAquaClaro}" />
            </Trigger>
            <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="False">
                <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource GrisClaro}" />
                <Setter Property="Cursor" Value="No" />
            </Trigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I noticed that you set the width and height of your button inside the button's style. And, if your StackPanel's width and height are smaller than your button's, then it would look kinda weird in your design window.

In your case, you might have assigned your StackPanel's size to the same size of your button, however, remember that your button has a margin of 5, which makes it look like shifted a little.

I tried something like you did in your example, it looks like this:
[image]

To fix this problem, you could try not specifying a detailed width/height inside the button style, or simply set them to auto and align them as stretched. And that would make your button set its width/height accordingly to the size of your StackPanel.

```
<Setter Property="Height" Value="auto" />
<Setter Property="Width" Value="auto" />
<Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Stretch" />
<Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Stretch" />
```

[image]